# Editor doesn't update

Tags: android, cursor, editor, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to update an editor, when user wants to change an info. But editor doesn't update. It just stores same information. I've cleared it in other class, and still it doesn't get new values. What should I do?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    h1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.h12);
    min1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.min12);
    d1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.d12);
    m1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m12);
    y1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.y12);
    button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    button8.setOnClickListener(this);
    sp = getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    abc = sp.getInt("d11",0);
    if (abc != 0)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.dc2.TEST3"));
    }
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    sp = getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    d11 = Integer.parseInt(d1.getText().toString());
    m11 = Integer.parseInt(m1.getText().toString());
    y11 = Integer.parseInt(y1.getText().toString());
    if( h1.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 )
    {
        h12 = 8;
        min12 = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        h12 = Integer.parseInt(h1.getText().toString());
        min12 = Integer.parseInt(min1.getText().toString());
    }
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("d11", d11);
    editor.putInt("m11", m11);
    editor.putInt("y11", y11);
    editor.putInt("h12", h12);
    editor.putInt("min12", min12);
    editor.apply();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TEST3.class);
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling clear() on the editor within the loop which actually deletes all the stored key-value pairs. Thus you end up with only the data stored in the last iteration.

See:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Comment: I've added clear() later. It doesn't work with and without clear()

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to do. Do you intend to save only a single age-name data at any given time, overriding the previous data, or do you expect to have more than one? Did you checked with the debugger to see the condition holds more than once and that the data is indeed different in each iteration?

Comment: Yes. I want to replace the previous data with the new one. But that doesn't happen

Comment: Try to get the editor before the loop, call commit() after the loop and remove the clear() call and see if it works. Better still - try to save the values of age and name in variables inside the loop without touching the editor and only after the loop save them to shared preferences. What are you doing in the not() method?

Comment: not(); just sends a notification, and If I press it, it opens new activity. This activity should receive information that I put in editor. And as I've said it only receives information that's put there for the first time

Comment: The commit method has a boolean return value which indicates success or failure. What are the results you get? The fact that only the data from the first time the condition holds is saved and not the last one even though you call to clear() makes me think that the code within the if condition within the loop is executed only once.

Comment: no it doesn't. It is executed every 30 seconds and I get a notification when it's needed

Comment: hi. Can you help me? I've edited my question. It uses another code, but still with sharedpreferences. WIthout loops. Please help me

Comment: Each time the user taps the button, you perform your calculation, store to database and then immediately start a service and a new screen. I don't know what you're doing in the service / class. How do you know the storing to database fails? Did you check the return value of commit? You can simply print it with System.out.println() to see the result. Perhaps you think it fails because you expect to see the result in the screen you're starting? Are you trying to read the shared preferences from any other place? Note that commit() is asynchronic and takes some time to execute.

Comment: You may want to consider replacing apply() with commit() to check whether the call succeeded or not. Recommend to do the calculations and writing to database on a separate background thread rather than on the main thread: new Thread() { @Override public void run() {...}}.start(); (If you call run() instead of start(), the code will still be executed on the main thread. Calling start() causes the code to be run on the newly defined thread).